# Weird keyboard behavior (Ubuntu only)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-16.04

I have the [G-LAB Keyz 200 N](http://the-g-lab.tech/en/keyboards/34-keyz-200-n.html) keyboard connected to a notebook with a dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 10 Pro.

It has a weird behavior when used in Ubuntu: Both left and right <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys all behave like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> thus making it impossible to use, among others, the editing functions shortcuts.

Troubleshhoting:

- It works fine, like any other keyboard, in Windows 10.
- The internal keyboard works fine in Ubuntu and Windows.
- Tested the keyboard in another PC running Ubuntu 18.04 and it again showed the same behavior.

I've googled a lot but couldn't find anything even remotely similar to the problem I'm having. The troubleshooting above seems to indicate there's no hardware problem - the internal keyboard works fine in both OSes and the external one works correctly in Windows 10 only. So the problem seems to be specific to this keyboard in Ubuntu.

What can be causing this weird behavior and is there any workaround? Suggestions for further troubleshooting are welcome.

**EDIT:**
Now googling by the hardware identifier `1c4f:0056 SiGma Micro` I did found others with the same exact problem - but apparently unsolved - :

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?34682-ctrl-alt-and-super-keys-bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720842

Here are the results for `lsusb -v -d 1c4f:0056` just in case someone can spot what makes this keyboard "special"...

```
 Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1c4f:0056 SiGma Micro 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1c4f SiGma Micro
  idProduct          0x0056 
  bcdDevice            3.70
  iManufacturer           1 SIGMACH1P
  iProduct                2 USB Keyboard
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      54
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     141
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: Is your bios up-to-date? This is probably a driver issue.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Yes, it is because there's no other. It's a 2014 System76 Bonobo (Ubuntu 16.04). But the same happens in another PC (Ubuntu 18.04) as I clearly mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is the keyboard loaded with usbhid?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen How can I check that? I know a lot more than the newbies here but I'm no Linux expert for sure. But I can use terminal if you want me to run commands :)

Comment: lsusb shows usb devices and in dmesg you can see initialization of those devices (needs grepping). This won't fix the problem though. You need have the drivers or maybe adding usbhid quirks works.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Thank you again. Question updated thanks to your idea. I knew about lsusb of course but I hadn't searched by hardware ID before. So it seems there's no solution other then wait for this devices to be correctly added to the kernel or something. Never heard of user installable keyboard drivers, let alone for Linux.

Comment: I think you should try to add the usbhid.quirks parameter to skip the loading of usbhid. It might work. Keyboard probably doesn't play nicely with usbhid.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen You mean as a boot parameter? Will it change something in the internal keyboard (i think it won't because *I think* the internal one isn't USB but still...)?